# python for loop output as array

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, for-loop, numpy

I have *XMl simulation* output, with many `vehicle` lines like:

```
    <routes>
        <vehicle id="8643" type="car" depart="0.03" departLane="free" departSpeed="max" fromTaz="63" toTaz="5">
        <vehicle id="8928" type="car" depart="0.34" departLane="free" departSpeed="max" fromTaz="663" toTaz="1147">
    </routes>
```

Currently I have the below which prints the required attributes.

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
e = ET.parse('trip_049.rou.xml')
root = e.getroot()

for vehicle in root.findall('vehicle'):
    id = vehicle.get('id')
    origin = vehicle.get('fromTaz')
    destination = vehicle.get('toTaz')
    print id,origin,destination
```

Which outputs:

```
8643 63 5
8928 663 1147
```

But I need the loop output to be stored in a numpy array or equivalent like:

```
id   origin destination
8643 63     5
8928 663    1147
```

Thank you in adavance

Comment: do you want them as a 2-d numpy array? And you want the elements to be of type string?

Comment: yes 2-d; for the elements in the example type integers, but I may have some string elements to add later. I will remove str from the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create a 2-dimensional list, and then at the end convert it to numpy array. Example -

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import numpy as np
e = ET.parse('trip_049.rou.xml')
root = e.getroot()

tdlist = []
for vehicle in root.findall('vehicle'):
    id = vehicle.get('id')
    origin = vehicle.get('fromTaz')
    destination = vehicle.get('toTaz')
    tdlist.append([id,origin,destination])

arraylst = np.array(tdlist)
```

The elements in `tdlist` and consequently in `arraylst` would be of type `str` . If you want them as integers, then you should convert them to int as -

```
id = int(vehicle.get('id'))
origin = int(vehicle.get('fromTaz'))
destination = int(vehicle.get('toTaz'))
```